# Displaying JWPlayer in Highslide using Firefox >16 failing under some circumstances

Tags: firefox, jwplayer, highslide

Seems to be the same problem that morphious started to describe in http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=24022&p=91079&hilit=jwplayer+firefox+17#p91079

Please look at http://www.lv-koerperbehinderte-bw.de/n/c8-0.php

This page works with IE, and it worked well with Firefox <17. In Firefox 17 and 18 everything works fine WHILE THE PAGE HAS NOT BEEN SCROLLED!

When scrolled, Highslide pops up, audio is playing and THOUGH BEING INVISIBLE, the JWPlayer controls work - if you know by heart where to put your clicks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is setting `objectLoadTime` to `'after'`. 
You can see the code in use in this demo: http://roadrash.no/hs-support/jwplayer/jwplayer-in-highslide-iframe.html (see source code for the “*JW player regular size*” link)

Your onclicks should look like this:

```
onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', width: 550, height: 152, objectLoadTime: 'after' } )"
```

Comment: Yabba Dabba Doo! Great! Thank You very much! <3